# Unable to delete mysql record through PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, delete-row

i want to delete the record in mysql database by just clicking on a link but i am unable to accomplish it, i am unable to understand the error.
Here is my code

HTML

```
<a href="processCategory.php?action=delete?id=(<?php echo $id; ?>);">Delete</a>
```

processCategory.php

```
    <?php
    require_once '../library/config.php';
    require_once '../library/functions.php';

    checkUser();

    $action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
    switch ($action) {

        case 'add' :
            addCategory();
            break;


        case 'delete' :
            deleteCategory();
            break;


        default :
            // if action is not defined or unknown
            // move to main category page
            header('Location: index.php');
    }


 function deleteCategory()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['id']) && (int)$_GET['id'] > 0) {
            $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
        } else {
            header('Location: index.php');
        }

        // delete the products
        $sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_vendors
                WHERE id = $id";
        dbQuery($sql);

        header('Location: ../vendor');
    }


    ?>
```

Comment: where is the error

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Shouldn't be like this: `$sql = "DELETE FROM tbl_vendors WHERE id =" .  $id;` ?? What's the error you're talking about?

Comment: @ Jay Blanchard  but he is changing id field to int sono  injection

Comment: You seem to have brackets around the ID in your link `id=(<?php echo $id; ?>)` which would evaluate to `id=(1)` so try `id=<?php echo $id; ?>` also just add exit('hello'); inside your dbQuery() to ensure your deleteCategory() function has access to dbQuery()

Comment: `(<?php echo $id; ?>)` - brackets, why? You're treating the `=` as a function.

Comment: @PhilS it worked thank you

Comment: No problem, glad it helped

Comment: True @vSugumar but we should always use prepared statements regardless of how we manipulate the data.

Comment: You might want to flag Guillermo Andres Fuentes Moral as correct as that answer is also correct

Comment: @ Jay Blanchard bro using prepared statements is a good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace ? with & and remove `"(" ")"` and `;` in your URL

```
<a href="processCategory.php?action=delete?id=(<?php echo $id; ?>);">Delete</a>
```

Your script processCategory.php Receives in the variable id this = (1) for example your out

```
echo (int) "(1)";
```

output

```
0
```

The correct code for the `<a>` tag should be as

```
<a href="processCategory.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $id; ?>">Delete</a>
```

Comment: You may want to make your answer more clear by posting the correct code instead of the wrong code...

Answer (score 0):

;">Delete
delete "()" maybe in php get the "($id)"